# Can I unstack() a subset of the columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have daily sales data of the format

```
col1  col2  col3  d_1  d_2  d_3  d_4
dog   yes   US    6    4    2    1
dog   no    US    4    3    2    5
cat   yes   US    4    2    0    1
```

where d_1, d_2, etc. represent numbers on days 1, 2, etc. I would like to end up with a new table in the format:

```
col1  col2  col3  day   sales
dog   yes   US    d_1   6
dog   yes   US    d_2   4
dog   yes   US    d_3   2
dog   yes   US    d_4   1
dog   no    US    d_1   4
dog   no    US    d_2   3
dog   no    US    d_3   2
dog   no    US    d_4   5
cat   yes   US    d_1   4
cat   yes   US    d_2   2
cat   yes   US    d_3   0
cat   yes   US    d_4   1
```

How can I do this? The closest I found is `df.set_index(['col1','col2','col3']).stack()` but it still doesn't quite do the above, it keeps seeing d_1,d_2, etc. as sort of an index, rather than converting it to real stacked data as in the example above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)

It comes with convenience arguments to rename the columns, making it the simplest way to reshape and rename all at once:

```
value_vars = ['d_1', 'd_2', 'd_3', 'd_4']
id_vars = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']
df.melt(id_vars, value_vars, var_name='day', value_name='sales')

   col1 col2 col3  day  sales
0   dog  yes   US  d_1      6
1   dog   no   US  d_1      4
2   cat  yes   US  d_1      4
3   dog  yes   US  d_2      4
4   dog   no   US  d_2      3
5   cat  yes   US  d_2      2
6   dog  yes   US  d_3      2
7   dog   no   US  d_3      2
8   cat  yes   US  d_3      0
9   dog  yes   US  d_4      1
10  dog   no   US  d_4      5
11  cat  yes   US  d_4      1
```

---

#### [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html)

Another possibility given you have well defined stubs (`'d_'`). Here the `day` column will be just the numbers as the `'d_'` gets stripped

```
(pd.wide_to_long(df, i=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], j='day', stubnames=['d'], sep='_')
   .rename(columns={'d': 'sales'})
   .reset_index())
```

Comment: Increased readabilty, less lines of code! I would accept this

Comment: @BjörnB Only slightly. If i crammed all of the `id_vars` and `value_vars` into the method it wouldn't be much shorter than yours. The biggest benefit is that it has self-documenting arguments for renaming. I find the level_0 renaming things to seem quite opaque, though sometimes it's necessary :D

Answer (score 2):

You provided already the perfect solution. Just reset the index after stacking. 
And use `.rename` with a dict to get the proper column headers

```
df =pd.DataFrame({'col1': {0: 'dog', 1: 'dog', 2: 'cat'},
     'col2': {0: 'yes', 1: 'no', 2: 'yes'},
     'col3': {0: 'US', 1: 'US', 2: 'US'},
     'd_1': {0: 6, 1: 4, 2: 4},
     'd_2': {0: 4, 1: 3, 2: 2},
     'd_3': {0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 0},
     'd_4': {0: 1, 1: 5, 2: 1}})
df_stacked =df.set_index(['col1', 'col2', 'col3']).stack()\
    .reset_index()\
    .rename(columns={'level_3':'day',0:'sales'})
```

Output

```
   col1 col2 col3  day  sales
0   dog  yes   US  d_1  6
1   dog  yes   US  d_2  4
2   dog  yes   US  d_3  2
3   dog  yes   US  d_4  1
4   dog   no   US  d_1  4
5   dog   no   US  d_2  3
6   dog   no   US  d_3  2
7   dog   no   US  d_4  5
8   cat  yes   US  d_1  4
9   cat  yes   US  d_2  2
10  cat  yes   US  d_3  0
11  cat  yes   US  d_4  1
```